# Default scaling of Bokeh plot not displaying on first render, need to manually reset

Tags: bokeh, holoviews

I am using this code to generate a layout with a point plot surrounded on the top and right by spike plots.  plot_3 displays to the right of the points plot, but on initial rendering all of the spikes are along the bottom of the axis and I have to hit the Bokeh reset icon to get them to appear in the expected location.

Experimenting with xlims and ylims has not fixed the issue. Once I hit the reset the display appears as expected.  Would like this to occur by default.  Thanks for any thoughts.  I have saved an html file that behaves the same way

```py
plot_1=hv.Points(plot_df_events, kdims=['Event_Date_Time','NumQuotes'], vdims=['Event_Date_Time','Symbol','BBO','NumTrades','NumQuotes','Adj_Close']).opts(
        opts.Points(width=800, height=600, tools=['hover'],
                    show_grid=True, legend_position='top_left',size=10,color='BBO',cmap='winter',alpha=0.75))          

# create a time plot of the ticker daily data to overlay on the plot of numtrades vs time
plot_2=hv.Curve(plot_df_continuous,kdims=['Event_Date_Time'],vdims=['Adj_Close_Scaled','Adj_Close'],label=f'{eval_date_ticker.result[0]}').opts(
        opts.Curve(width=800, height=600, tools=['hover'],
                   show_grid=True))

# Get the NumQuotes and Time_Stamp data from your context
x1 = plot_df_events['Event_Date_Time']
x2 = plot_df_events['Adj_Close_Scaled']
y1 = plot_df_events['NumTrades']
y2 = plot_df_events['NumTrades']
xrange1 = (analysis_time_begin, analysis_time_end)
yrange1 = (analysis_range_min, analysis_range_max)

dt = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time(9, 30))

plot_3=hv.Spikes((x2,y2),vdims=['Adj_Close']).opts(
    opts.Spikes(alpha=0.5,width=200, height=600, tools=['hover'],line_width=5))

plot_4=hv.Spikes((x1,y1),vdims=['NumTrades']).opts(
    opts.Spikes(alpha=0.5,width=800, height=200, tools=['hover'],line_width=5,xlim=xrange1))

new_layout=((plot_1*plot_2) << plot_3 << plot_4)

hv.save(new_layout, 'my_layout.html')

new_layout
```